# Survey or rating system to easily plug into existing .net code?

Tags: .net, web-applications, plugins

I have an existing .NET ecommerce app. A new client would like a built-in rating system.
Rather than re-inventing the wheel I was wondering if there was one off-the-shelf, that I could easily plug into existing C# .NET code.
It would need to reference a product record from the existing db.

The requirement include the ability to add questions, almost like a survey builder.

Does anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dataillusion.com/feedbackserver/

Its not free, but looks pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, If it saves time paying for code is often better :)